# Finding the double integral if $f$ is continuous.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, continuity, indefinite-integrals

Let $f:[-\sqrt{2}\pi, \sqrt{2}\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Calculate
$$\int_{-\sqrt{2}\pi}^{\sqrt{2}\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} f(y^{2})e^{\frac{|x|-y}{2}} \sin(x) dydx$$

Do you have any ideas for this problem? I have problems with this part, $$\int_{-1}^{1} f(y^{2}) e^{-\frac{y}{2}}dy$$

I think it should be integration for parts, with $u=e^{-\frac{y}{2}}$ and $dv=f(y^{2})$ since $f$ is continuous but then $v= \int_{-1}^{1} f(y^{2}) dy$?

Comment: Consider the $x$ part: $\int_{-\sqrt2\pi}^{\sqrt2\pi} e^{\frac{|x|}2}\sin(x)\,dx$. Since the integrand is an odd function, so $\int_{-\sqrt2\pi}^{\sqrt2\pi} e^{\frac{|x|}2}\sin(x)\,dx=0$, and the original integral is $0$?

Comment: That's true, I thought that I have to do something with the function $f$.